# Correctly target previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="fotorama"><img src="img1.jpg">/></div>
   <div class="fotorama-fullscreen">Open fullscreen</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
   <div class="fotorama"><img src="img2.jpg">/></div>
   <div class="fotorama-fullscreen">Open fullscreen</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
   <div class="fotorama"><img src="img3.jpg">/></div>
   <div class="fotorama-fullscreen">Open fullscreen</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".fotorama-fullscreen").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.on('click', function(){
        $("#wrapper").fadeTo(1000, 0, function(){
            $("#main").isotope("destroy");
            $this.prev().trigger('fullscreenopen'); <== My trigger
            $("#wrapper").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        });
    });
});
```

I have a bounch of galleries which I open in fullscreen by pressing a button. The above code works on desk but when I'm on an iPad it doesn't open the gallery which leads me to think `.prev();` doesn't work on an ipad? Or am I doing something wrong in finding and addressing the correct path?

Comment: Are you sure 'click' event is fired properly, don't you have to use `touchstart` instead? I wonder, btw, why didn't you just write something like `$('.fotorama-fullscreen').on('click', function() { ... })`...

Comment: just tried using simply $('.fotorama-fullscreen').on('click', function() { ... }) but no luck. Works fine on desktop but not on the iPad. It is more to do with the .prev() and finding the previous div, no need of touchstart here. If i insert the previous div class, it works fine $("fotorama").trigger('fullscreenopen'); but that will open ALL .fotorama galleries, I need to open the correct gallery for each clicked button and .prev() should work :(